# Update table procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I have 3 table which are

Item : **Item_Number PK**, Item_Name, Current_Price,Production_cost.

Ingredient : **Ingredient_Number PK**, Ingredient_Name, Ingredient_Cost

Item_Ingredient: ***Item_Number PK/FK, Ingredient_Number PK/FK***, Quantity_Needed

1 Item is made by 3 or 4 different ingredients.
Production_Cost for each Item is calculate by the sum of all (ingredient_Cost * Quantity_Needed).
I'm trying to create the procedure with the cursor to update the Production_cost fo all item if the Production-Cost < sum of all (ingredient_Cost * Quantity_Needed).But i dont't know how to calculate that in my procedure.
Can you guys help me to fix it? This is the first part of my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_Check_Cost
AUTHID CURRENT USER 
IS
V_Production_Cost item.Production_cost%Type;
V_New_Production_Cost number (6,2);
V_Item_Number number (5,0);
Cursor C_Cost IS
 select ii.item_number, SUM(in.ingredient_cost * ii.quantity_Needed)
 from item.ingredient ii, ingredient in
where ii.ingredient_number = in_ingredient_number
group by ii.item_number
Begin
Open C_Cost;
Fetch C_Cost into V_Item_Number, V_New_Production_Cost;
 While C_Product_Cost%FOUND LOOP
select Production_Cost
into V_Production_Cost
From Item
Where Item_Number = V_Item_Number;

If V_Production_Cost < V_New_Production_Cost THEN
 UPDATE Item
 Set Production_Cost = V_New_Production_Cost
 Where Item_Number = V_Item_Number;
End If;

Fetch C_Cost into V_Item_Number, V_New_Production_Cost;
 End loop;
Close C_Cost;
End PR_Check_cost;/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Comment: Ok plz explain for me here you want to check if `Production-Cost  > (ingredient_Cost * Quantity_Needed).`  then update `Production-Cost` to something ?

Comment: Do you need it to be a procedure or could you use a single sql update statement instead?

Comment: If you add on your question a sample data from that tree tables and what would be the result from that sample I'm pretty sure it can be done with a single update statement.

Comment: Yeah, If Production-Cost < sum of all (ingredient_Cost * Quantity_Needed) then Update the Product_Cost with the sum of all (ingredient_Cost * Quantity_Needed) value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get it done with a single UPDATE statement with something like this:

```
UPDATE item     
SET production_cost = (SELECT SUM(t2.ingredient_cost * t1.quantity_needed)
                       FROM item_ingredient t1 JOIN ingredient t2 ON t1.ingredient_number = t2.ingredient_number
                       WHERE t1.item_number = item.item_number)
WHERE production_cost < (SELECT SUM(t2.ingredient_cost * t1.quantity_needed)
                         FROM item_ingredient t1 JOIN ingredient t2 ON     t1.ingredient_number = t2.ingredient_number
                         WHERE t1.item_number = item.item_number);
```

I don't know if you just wanted to get it done or learn about cursors and procedures, in that case, you could use a procedure like this (but this would be highly inefficient):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_check_cost AUTHID CURRENT USER IS  
  v_production_cost item.production_cost%TYPE;

  CURSOR c_cost IS
    SELECT it.item_number, SUM(in.ingredient_cost * it.quantity_needed) production_cost
    FROM item_ingredient it, ingredient in
    WHERE it.ingredient_number = in.ingredient_number
    GROUP BY it.item_number;
BEGIN

  FOR r IN c_cost LOOP
    SELECT production_cost
    INTO v_production_cost
    FROM item
    WHERE item_number = r.item_number;

    IF v_production_cost < r.production_cost THEN
      UPDATE item
      SET production_cost = r.production_cost
      WHERE item_number = r.item_number;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END pr_check_cost;
```

Note that I haven't compiled the code, it might have some errors in it.

Comment: Tanks for your help.I want to learn more about procedure and cursor in this case.I can get it done by using the trigger but it's a little bit tricky for me if I have to use only the procedure and cursor

Comment: @GiangNguyen I just edited my answer to include an example procedure

Comment: I just updated my code in the first post and gonna test to see how it work. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is a bit too complicated for what you are trying to achieve.
A better, simpler way, IMO, is to run a cursor of the entire item table and then run this query for every item, comparing its outcome to the current production cost -

```
select sum(total_ing_cost)
into calc_cost
from (
select (d.ingredient_cost * q.quantity_needed) as total_ing_cost
from item i, ingredient d, item_ingredient q
where i.item_number = q.item_number
and d.ingredient_number = q.ingredient_number
and item_number = current_item_in_cursor
)
```

I don't have Oracle installed on this station yet so the query's syntax might not be exactly right but the idea is there and you're welcome to use it.

Comment: You mean I should use the cursor to select the the Item_Number and Production_Cost in the Item table and fetch them into V_ Item_Number and V_Production_Cost?
In this case, with only the procedure,cursor and joining table, I don't know how to get the sum of all ingredient cost and feel a little bit tricky :(

Comment: the sum of all ingredient cost is the result of the query I've attached.